# how to use root project in sub-project?

Tags: android

The followings are my situation.

[image]

and build.gradle of app (root project)

```
dependencies {
   compile project(':magicfilter')
   compile project(':zgallery')
   compile project(':dialogs')
}
```

I want to class of app (root project) in magicfilter, zgallery, dialogs (sub-projects).

But I can't refer classes of app in sub-projects..

How do I call the class of the root project in a sub project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can not. Even if it is possible that is not supposed to be done. If you need to call something of the main module on the other modules maybe the architecture of the project it is not well defined and maybe it is better to structure it on other way.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not a good design pattern, or effective distribution of your model, why you need access your app project in sub project?

Comment: Thank you for your answer but other gave me more detail guide.
Have a good day.